# I need to identify the genus of this colony just by its morphology, can somebody help me?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, morphology

1. it was grown on TSA
2. it's a mesophilic bacteria.

(it was contaminated by E. coli, so ignore the clearer and smoother colonies).

[image: =c]

Comment: Do you have any more information? Is this a school project? why only the genus? "mesophilic" --> what exact conditions did you grow it under?

Comment: @MaximilianPress yes it was supposed to be a lab work in my uni, but because of the virus I don't have more information about it and still have to write a report and the task is to identify the genus just by its characteristics. I only know that it was grown on TSA, under mesophilic conditions (~30 C) for a week. My guess is this is Bacillus genus since the biofilm is wrinkly, but I want to hear other opinions.

Comment: Perhaps you were to do a Gram stain as well; which was cancelled. I had thought Bacillus also.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler yes, I'm sure gram staining was planned too. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Maybe present  an analysis based upon each of the possible results of a Gram stain also.